# ES6 Map: transform values

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-map

I'm working on a project where I frequently have to transform every value in an ES6 map:

```
const positiveMap = new Map(
  [
    ['hello', 1],
    ['world', 2]
  ]
);

const negativeMap = new Map<string, number>();
for (const key of positiveMap.keys()) {
  negativeMap.set(key, positiveMap.get(key) * -1);
}
```

Just wondering if there is maybe a better way of doing this?  Ideally a one liner like `Array.map()`.

Bonus points (not really), if it compiles in typescript!

Comment: @AluanHaddad `.entries()` returns an iterator, not an array of key/value pairs. That won't work.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you're right. (hits head with hand)

Comment: for anyone that cares (about microbenchmarks) copying manually using `.forEach` is an order of magnitude faster on V8.  Mutating in-place is another order of magnitude faster.  Not that it will actually really matter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `Array.from` 2<sup>nd</sup> argument, a map-style callback:

```js
const positiveMap = new Map([['hello', 1],['world', 2]]),
    negativeMap = new Map(Array.from(positiveMap, ([k, v]) => [k, -v]));

console.log([...negativeMap]);
```

Comment: It saves on creating an intermediate array before the mapping is initiated.

Comment: any idea why this throws a type error (in typescript)? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20positiveMap%20%3D%20new%20Map(%5B%5B'hello'%2C%201%5D%2C%5B'world'%2C%202%5D%5D)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20negativeMap%20%3D%20new%20Map(Array.from(positiveMap%2C%20(%5Bk%2C%20v%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%5Bk%2C%20-v%5D))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%5B...negativeMap%5D)%3B

Comment: looks like I can just force the types using `as [string, number]` at the end of `array.from`

Answer (score 3):

You could transform it into array using spread syntax `...`, apply `map()` method and then again transform it to `Map`

```js
const positiveMap = new Map([['hello', 1],['world', 2]]);

const negativeMap = new Map([...positiveMap].map(([k, v]) => [k, v * -1]))
console.log([...negativeMap])
```

Comment: very nice! Exactly what I was looking for.  I've have had issues in the past with `ts-jest` not properly transpiling the spread operator on a map... but that doesn't really relate to the questions at hand

Comment: @NSjonas you can use `Array.from` instead of `[...]`

Comment: any thoughts on how to make it compile in TS?  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20positiveMap%20%3D%20new%20Map(%5B%5B'hello'%2C%201%5D%2C%5B'world'%2C%202%5D%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20negativeMap%20%3D%20new%20Map(%5B...positiveMap%5D.map((%5Bk%2C%20v%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%5Bk%2C%20v%20*%20-1%5D))%0D%0Aconsole.log(%5B...negativeMap%5D)

Comment: nvm, just need to force the return of array from with ` as [string, number]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can extend `Map` with your own class and include functionality to generically iterate it like an array:

```js
class ArrayMap extends Map {
  map (fn, thisArg) {
    const { constructor: Map } = this;
    const map = new Map();
    
    for (const [key, value] of this.entries()) {
      map.set(key, fn.call(thisArg, value, key, this));
    }
    
    return map;
  }
  
  forEach (fn, thisArg) {
    for (const [key, value] of this.entries()) {
      fn.call(thisArg, value, key, this);
    }
  }
  
  reduce (fn, accumulator) {
    const iterator = this.entries();
    
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
      if (this.size === 0) throw new TypeError('Reduce of empty map with no initial value');
      accumulator = iterator.next().value[1];
    }
    
    for (const [key, value] of iterator) {
      accumulator = fn(accumulator, value, key, this);
    }
    
    return accumulator;
  }
  
  every (fn, thisArg) {
    for (const [key, value] of this.entries()) {
      if (!fn.call(thisArg, value, key, this)) return false;
    }
    
    return true;
  }
  
  some (fn, thisArg) {
    for (const [key, value] of this.entries()) {
      if (fn.call(thisArg, value, key, this)) return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  }
  
  // ...
}

const positiveMap = new ArrayMap(
  [
    ['hello', 1],
    ['world', 2]
  ]
);
const negativeMap = positiveMap.map(value => -value);

negativeMap.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key, value));
```

I threw in `reduce()`, `every()` and `some()` for free. Implement as many or as few of the methods you like or need.

Comment: what are your thoughts on just extending via prototype instead (using global `types.d.ts`)?  Bad idea?

Comment: I have little experience with TypeScript, but my general advice is if you're introducing new functionality, put it in a new class so that you don't render native classes incompatible with existing type definitions for them.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a generic typescript function based on trincot's answer

```
function transformMap<K, V, U>(source: Map<K, V>, func: (key: K, value: V) => U): Map<K, U> {
  return new Map(Array.from(source, (v) => [v[0], func(v[0], v[1])]));
}
```

and use it like this

```
transformMap(positiveMap, (key, value) => -value)
```