# Nested grouping by one or more levels

Tags: typescript, data-structures

Given the following data structure:

```js
const data = [
  { A: 1, B: 12, C: 123 },
  { A: 1, B: 122, C: 1233 },
  { A: 2, B: 22, C: 223 }
];
```

I would like to implement a function called `groupBy` with the following signature:

```js
function groupBy<T, By extends keyof T>(object: T[], by: ...By[]): Map<By[0], Map<By[1], ..., Map<number, T[]>...>
```

which I would be able to call like:

```js
const A = groupBy(data, "A"); // Map<number, { A: number, B: number, C: number }[]>;
const AB = groupBy(data, "A", "B"); // Map<number, Map<number, { A: number, B: number, C: number }[]>>;
const ABC = groupBy(data, "A", "B", "C"); // Map<number, Map<number, Map<number, ...>>;
```

Unfortunately, I was only able to [implement `groupBy` with a single level](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE5xABwEIE8A8AKogKYAeUJYAJgM6JwBGAVidADSIDSpFVdiANYlccYIkIA+ABQQ4AG3ltYCAFwSA2gF1OMSqgCGlEuq4BKdQFkDmIhq47NWyYgDeAWABQiRHLC0oRABbGysbOwdOQm0XAF5EMBIAd0RrTGkzAG4vLx9gOFREWQQAxD0SIIZxOUVleDAzN1yfXxLAgwgIEBD5IxJqRHiQzAA6ZBIoaXKgjXLDYy0s5p8YcWkOrp6+gdjdxHBqEmAYROpGj28Wn2GR2gmpyhm5vpJHWcfF7MufAF9SeTuTW+LRud0m03eJHmJFenA0IwRG26Bl6lGoug+S2BP2aOM8zVQExAqCQwy+PyAA):

```js
function groupBy<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(collection: T[], iteratee: K): Map<T[K], T[]> {
  const map: Map<T[K], T[]> = new Map();

  for (const item of collection) {
    const accumalated = map.get(item[iteratee]);
    if (accumalated === undefined) {
      map.set(item[iteratee], [item]);
    } else {
      map.set(item[iteratee], [...accumalated, item]);
    }
  }

  return map;
}
```

Comment: When you say `// Map<number, { A: number, B: number, C: number }>;` you mean `// Map<number, { A: number, B: number, C: number }[]>;`, right?  In general the leaves of the tree holds arrays, not individual objects, right?

Comment: @jcalz you are correct, it's my typo. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's describe `groupBy()` at the type level, by giving it a strongly-typed call signature:

```
type GroupedBy<T, K> = K extends [infer K0, ...infer KR] ?
    Map<T[Extract<K0, keyof T>], GroupedBy<T, KR>> : T[];

// call signature
function groupBy<T, K extends Array<keyof T>>(
  objects: readonly T[], ...by: [...K]
): GroupedBy<T, K>;
```

So `groupBy()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the type of the elements of the `objects` array, as well as `K`, a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of the keys of `T` corresponding to the `...by` [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).  The function returns `GroupedBy<T, K>`.

So what's `GroupedBy<T, K>`?  It's a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types).  If the tuple `K` is empty, then it will just be `T[]` (since grouping an array by nothing should yield the same array).  Otherwise, we use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to split the `K` tuple into the first element, `K0`, and the rest, `KR`.  Then `GroupedBy<T, K>` will be a `Map` whose key type is the type of property of `T` at key `K0` (conceptually this is just an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[K0]`, but the compiler doesn't know that `K0` will be a key of `T`, so we use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to convince it... so `T[Extract<K0, keyof T>]`) and whose value type is, recursing, `GroupedBy<T, KR>`.

Let's make sure the compiler does the right thing:

```
const A = groupBy(data, "A"); 
// Map<number, { A: number, B: number, C: number }[]>;

const AB = groupBy(data, "A", "B"); 
// Map<number, Map<number, { A: number, B: number, C: number }[]>>;

const ABC = groupBy(data, "A", "B", "C"); /* Map<number, Map<number, Map<number, {
    A: number;
    B: number;
    C: number;
}[]>>> */
```

Looks good.  Just to be sure, let's change `number` into something else:

```
const otherData = [
    { str: "a", num: 1, bool: true },
    { str: "a", num: 1, bool: false },
    { str: "a", num: 2, bool: true }
];
const grouped = groupBy(otherData, "str", "num", "bool")
/* const grouped: Map<string, Map<number, Map<boolean, {
    str: string;
    num: number;
    bool: boolean;
}[]>>> */
```

Also looks good.

---

Now let's implement `groupBy()`. The compiler can't possibly follow the recursive conditional typing inside the implementation (see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)), so let's loosen things up by making it an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with a single, strongly-typed call signature, and a loose implementation signature using [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  We have to be careful to do it right because the compiler won't catch type bugs.

Anyway, here's a possible implementation:

```
// implementation
function groupBy(objects: readonly any[], ...by: Array<PropertyKey>) {
    if (!by.length) return objects;
    const [k0, ...kr] = by;
    const topLevelGroups = new Map<any, any[]>();
    for (const obj of objects) {
        let k = obj[k0];
        let arr = topLevelGroups.get(k);
        if (!arr) {
            arr = [];
            topLevelGroups.set(k, arr);
        }
        arr.push(obj);
    }
    return new Map(Array.from(topLevelGroups, ([k, v]) => ([k, groupBy(v, ...kr)])));

}
```

If the `by` array is empty, return the `objects` array unchanged; this corresponds to the base case of `GroupedBy<T, K>` where `K` is `[]`.  Otherwise, we split `by` into the first element `k0` and the rest of it `kr`.  We then go through and do a top-level grouping of `objects` by the values in their `k0` key.  This involves getting the right making sure that we initialize arrays before pushing things into them.  And finally, at the end, we transform that top-level grouping (using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48571139/2887218)), recursing, applying `groupBy()` to each array of objects.

Let's see if it works:

```
console.log(A);
/* Map (2) {1 => [{
  "A": 1,
  "B": 12,
  "C": 123
}, {
  "A": 1,
  "B": 122,
  "C": 1233
}], 2 => [{
  "A": 2,
  "B": 22,
  "C": 223
}]}  */

console.log(AB);
/* Map (2) {1 => Map (2) {12 => [{
  "A": 1,
  "B": 12,
  "C": 123
}], 122 => [{
  "A": 1,
  "B": 122,
  "C": 1233
}]}, 2 => Map (1) {22 => [{
  "A": 2,
  "B": 22,
  "C": 223
}]}}  */
```

Also looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDXMDeMAggFwwCMANDAEJnkBM1AwvQwMwwC+lOehpCtToUGTGK1HtOPPrgFlxIsS0UduWALoBuLFigBPAA4BTGAHEATiACupuDQMAeACrUA0gD40MdzBMAHlAmYHAQmACWYABmJpa+AAzUAHSpUbHx7gBKmjAA-HIwALIIRq4YAKJBlgjAUE7uSTAA1iYGINEwLp6a1Fa29o6uHlme3mQuGDp6APQzMMAIADZLMBARAOZgSDaWJljRNmB1EeAwG9Z2Q26+-kEhYcSWNc6t7Z3dngAUIABGAFYmOoQMh7BBwcBLAxdKYpVK-AxkDCpZLuTQASjI-TsJgczhuXl0WDmMAiAFsjEsTGSQsgoKcwAcjiczhcBo4fgCgVAQTAwRCwFCYAgwAZYTAUQiyERnghnAAFaymSyGdxtTzogiFCKdL4AQgRySpYA2UAAFpq9lBdmAYH9AcDdHgFuBoJhmk0Uc1LLl0AinXhQJBYFAQEYADImABuJiW2KM4XQYBMAHdiqUnCKDNQs1NvuiA7hoiB4l8g277XbOvbuRBNfhCs6qbBmj57RgPdNnU2TLAEM8fKGI9HY-GIMkNr2vs0C428DqYPr+5Z63Pu8KB+gpoX13gh5GY3HLgnkhAp80c89Z7uNDfl8kjDYIGbOf9r3guIUrTaYMm0yUjC+GUXmSaJrDJL59xHI8Bggagvg7agowxNBvAQi9zmPDkozhZJvXRDF0VnT8sHLWAiB8NkrgML5EGQagACIiAYgsYBJACnDAGwyV+OJqAUX9uN4yxhDILieL4iQxKEuJuDzXQyOIGhKKwmi6IQRjmMYmgWO0Nj5g48ThOoQyZJEghiGkiTzJEIzJMkOz4i4PNPAU11yJoZgVPZNSkA0mAmIY7SgoC5hdLYgAqdMykckyM1i6LOLM-jCkERyd1ssydwcrKsGczQxm8CKZj0csQCpI0QA2IDZxmKKAMXBh63IVDMAbXBAvoXgOp0thutChi2HYPKUo65iur4BjetEJhJrCobhq4XoYAYVqMHagLxpW-qpsGlbZo6+b9sWzQuFwYrStdcqTEq6qiBoWr6tKRrmtahqviaghGDWjbOqESbpsYHajsYE7qEYVbUG8dbJq2qgAb2iHgcRjgTp4Fa3uer5yHrMQfthvaDoC6aVDmwmODy06zpgC7LuDO1zTiAARPyfGwZ1CGgSwyAYhAQvErqYF+EByrIKBLBsMxZA5tZxZ5vnqAFoQhZFpYyGiZYz24fr5Fl7mAoVwSyUUahhdFmBxcljRpkUqj7G86ifkZywWfogKuZChjxM9s2lhY4kott49cTIDiuaiDY4pi5LEt9kwRVGvAubIcOTR3JX0sKX2yDjkVdHywqaZmIA)

Comment: Every time I think I've reached to an impossible solution, you prove me wrong. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: A question tho - would have it been possible to achieve it without `any`?

Comment: You could probably do it without `any`, maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk52PN)... but you still need type assertions because the compiler will not understand that the return value is of the right type.

Comment: @jcalz could you provide any info on having that work to return a nested object instead of a Map? I've made attempts on three different occasions and it makes my brain a bit melty